# Fetch complete user record in DJango

Tags: django

Below is the user record present in MySQL Database table - `auth_user`

**Please click the image if it is not clear here**
[image]

Below is my code present in View.py file.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class loginController(View):
    def get(self, request):
        userobj = User.objects.filter(username = 'username')
        return HttpResponse(request.POST.get('username'));
```

It returns just the username. Can you please suggest that why it just fetch the username and not the complete record?

Please let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the list of user objects represented by username.  You can access all the properties of object as (obj.property). eg: if you have first_name in your user model

```
u = userobj.first()
u.first_name
u.last_name
```

Comment: `u = userobj.first()` this code just returns the username

Comment: its not the user name its user object which is represented by username

Answer (score -1):

```
    If you want to fetch the complete user information, then you have to return User object, so that you can iterate throught that User object in your template

    Example:-
    Views.py

    from django.views import generic

    class loginController(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'project_app/user-list.html'
        model = User

        def get_queryset(self):
            userlist = User.objects.all()
            return userlist


project_app/user-list.html

{% if object_list %}
 {% for user in object_list %}
  <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
  <p>{{ user.first_name }}</p>
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```